# How to compare the decline in results between multiple groups

Tags: r, regression, model-comparison

I've tested a number of fruit samples for weight loss over time (shelf-life assessment).
I want to compare weight loss between the different samples.

My initial idea was to use a linear regression model for each sample and then compare the models' estimates.

Is this the right way to tackle this issue and if so, which tests should I use for this?

P.S I'm using R

Comment: I guess you are looking for this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435644/is-there-a-method-to-look-for-significant-difference-between-two-linear-regressi

Comment: Thanks @AminShn. Will the method given in this example work with 3 factors (Fladen A, Fladen B and Fladen C)?

Comment: Yes, it does work.